# How to randomly choose element in array column of different size?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given a dataframe with a column of arrays of integers with different sizes:

```
scala> sampleDf.show()
+------------+
|      arrays|
+------------+
|[15, 16, 17]|
|[15, 16, 17]|
|        [14]|
|        [11]|
|        [11]|
+------------+

scala> sampleDf.printSchema()
root
 |-- arrays: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

I would like to generate a new column with a random chosen item in each array.
I've tried two solution:
1. Using UDF:

```
  import scala.util.Random

  def getRandomElement(arr: Array[Int]): Int = {
    arr(Random.nextInt(arr.size))
  }

  val getRandomElementUdf = udf{arr: Array[Int] => getRandomElement(arr)}

  sampleDf.withColumn("randomItem", getRandomElementUdf('arrays)).show
```

crashes on the last line with a long error message: (extracts)

```
...
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (array<int>) => int)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [I
```

I've tried with the alternative udf definition:

```
 val getRandomElementUdf = udf[Int, Array[Int]] (getRandomElement)
```

but I get the same error.
2. Second method by creating intermediary columns with a random index in the range of the corresponding array:

```
 // Return a dataframe with a column with random index from column of Arrays with different sizes
 def choice(df: DataFrame, colName: String): DataFrame = {
    df.withColumn("array_size", size(col(colName)))
      .withColumn("random_idx", least('array_size, floor(rand * 'array_size))) 
 }

 choice(sampleDf, "arrays").show
```

outputs:

```
+------------+----------+----------+
|      arrays|array_size|random_idx|
+------------+----------+----------+
|[15, 16, 17]|         3|         2|
|[15, 16, 17]|         3|         1|
|        [14]|         1|         0|
|        [11]|         1|         0|
|        [11]|         1|         0|
+------------+----------+----------+
```

and ideally we would like to use the column `random_idx` to choose an item in column `arrays`, kind of:

```
sampleDf.withColumn("choosen_item", 'arrays.getItem('random_idx))
```

Unfortunaltely, `getItem` cannot take a column as argument.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: The error you get is due to the use of an Array in your UDF

Comment: You're right: I replaced `Array[Int]` by `WrappedArray[Int]` in  `getRandomElement` and `getRandomElementUdf` definitions and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below `udf` to select the `random` element from the array as

```
val getRandomElement = udf ((array: Seq[Integer]) => {
  array(Random.nextInt(array.size))
})


df.withColumn("c1", getRandomElement($"arrays"))
  .withColumn("c2", getRandomElement($"arrays"))
  .withColumn("c3", getRandomElement($"arrays"))
  .withColumn("c4", getRandomElement($"arrays"))
  .withColumn("c5", getRandomElement($"arrays"))

  .show(false)
```

You can see the `random` element selected in each use as a new column.

```
+------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|arrays      |c1 |c2 |c3 |c4 |c5 |
+------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|[15, 16, 17]|15 |16 |16 |17 |16 |
|[15, 16, 17]|16 |16 |17 |15 |15 |
|[14]        |14 |14 |14 |14 |14 |
|[11]        |11 |11 |11 |11 |11 |
|[11]        |11 |11 |11 |11 |11 |
+------------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remain udf-free, here is a possibility:
first add a key to the dataframe outputed by `choice` (assume its name is `choiceDf`)

```
val myDf = choiceDf.withColumn("key", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

then create an intermediary dataframe that explode the arrays column and keep the index of the values

```
val tmp = myDf.select('key, posexplode('arrays))
```

finally join using key and  `random_idx`

```
myDf.join(tmp.withColumnRenamed("pos", "random_idx"), Seq("key", "random_idx", "left")
```

the item you look for is stored in the column `col`

```
+---+----------+------------+----------+---+
|key|random_idx|      arrays|array_size|col|
+---+----------+------------+----------+---+
|  0|         2|[15, 16, 17]|         3| 17|
|  1|         1|[15, 16, 17]|         3| 16|
|  2|         0|        [14]|         1| 14|
+---+----------+------------+----------+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the random element from an array by one line using Spark-SQL

```
sampleDF.createOrReplaceTempView("sampleDF")
spark.sql("select arrays[Cast((FLOOR(RAND() * FLOOR(size(arrays)))) as INT)] as random from sampleDF")
```